# two different sign up forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm making an application, using Devise, where average-Joe-citizen can ask questions, which will hopefully be answered by some-sort of Medical Professional. On my homepage, I want to have two sign up links like this

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Are you a Medical Professional?", new_user_registration_path %></li>
```

but I want them to obviously display different signup forms, which necessitates different routes I assume.

The only difference on the User model will be that, for the Medical Professional, the boolean attribute for Medical Professional will be 'true' whereas it's false for the average-Joe.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1: Persisting the selection in a hidden field**

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Are you a Medical Professional?", new_user_registration_path(medical: true) %></li>
```

You could make use of a parameter in the route for a quick solution: `new_user_registrations_path(medical: true)` will result in a route with an appended `?medical=true`).

In your registration form you could check if the parameter is set and then set a hidden field to remember the setting.

```
# Remember the medical user setting
<%= f.check_box :medical, checked: params[:medical].true?, hidden: true %>
```

I'm not certain whether the check_box tag will work like that, feel free to edit if you find the syntax to be different. Hope it helps.

**Approach 2: Overriding the Devise RegistrationsController**

This is totally possible, just see the docs. However I would feel a little weary when doing this, as the internals of the Devise controller might change, and you'd need to keep these changes in sync manually.

**Approach 3: As requested: Displaying different signup forms**

Using the parameter you might decide **in the view** which form to render (not nice, not stylish, but working :-D).

```
<% if params[:medical] %>
   <%= render 'medical_signup_form' %>
<% else %>
   <%= render 'regular_signup_form' %>
<% end %>
```

Both forms would then need to carry all the relevant signup attributes. That's certainly some code duplication, but in my opinion worth not having to override Device's controller action that might need to change without you noticing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks like it would work, however, I'm hoping to show a different signup page depending on the link they click. Is there a way to check the param at the controller level and render a different  page (with a different form on it)? If you modify your answer, please don't remove the information you already provided as it is very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted another approach for different forms. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just to let you know, this didn't work: <% if params[:medical].true? %>  Instead, I had to do <% if params[:medical] %> because if there is no medical param, then there is no true method for it. However, overall the solution was great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, I've updated the answer to include your feedback. Glad to help!

Comment: No problem. I didn't test it, but I'm guessing if I did (medical: false) in the other route, then checking for the .true? on params would have worked.